# Can't figure out syntax of compact struct declarations

Tags: c, struct

Neither of these snippets of code work:

```
int main() {
    struct mystruct {
        int a;
        char* b;
        char* c;
    } e,f;
    e = {5, "blaat", "boe"};

    return 0;
}
```

> Error: syntax error for '{' token

```
int main() {
    struct mystruct {
        int a;
        char* b;
        char* c;
    } e,f;
    struct mystruct e = {5, "blaat", "boe"};

    return 0;
}
```

> Error: previous declaration of 'e' was here

What *is* the correct way to do this?

Comment: C99 allows struct assignment outside the declaration, so your first code snippet should be ok for C99 compiler

Comment: Look at the other question here, regarding swapping structs, using an array, read the code carefully...it will help you.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138872/swapping-elements-in-an-array-of-structs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compound literal assignment is new with C99, and the syntax would be

```
e = (struct mystruct) {5, "blaat", "boe"};
```

The cast expression is required.

In C89, you either have to initialize `e` as part of the declaration:

```
struct mystruct {int a; char *b; char *c} e = {5, "blaat", "boe"};
```

or

```
struct mystruct e = {5, "blaat", "boe"};
```

or you have to assign members individually:

```
struct mystruct e;
e.a = 5;
e.b = "blaat";
e.c = "boe";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int main() {
    struct mystruct {
        int a;
        char* b;
        char* c;
    } f;
    struct mystruct e = {5, "blaat", "boe"};

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
e = {5, "blaat", "boe"};
```

This can **only** be done during initialisation and since you've already initialised 'e' as part of your struct declaration, you can't follow up with it. I recommend [Neil's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139083/cant-figure-out-syntax-of-compact-struct-declarations/2139093#2139093) method.

Comment: With C99 this is no longer so, but the given syntax is wrong:

    struct mystruct e;
    ...
    e = (struct mystruct){5, "blah", "boe"};

This assigns e to a "compound literal", and uses the implicit assignment created for all structs (which is translated into something similar to an inline memcopy() call).

Answer (score 0):

Either initialize the members in one go like the following:

```
int main() {
struct mystruct {
    int a;
    char* b;
    char* c;
} f;
  struct mystruct e = {5, "blaat", "boe"};

  return 0;
}
```

or assign values to them later like the following:

```
int main() {
 struct mystruct {
    int a;
    char* b;
    char* c;
 }e,f;

 /* a,b,c are initialized with unknown values */

   e.a=5; /*Assignment instead of initialization*/
   e.b="blaat";
   e.c="boe";

   return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
int main() {
    struct mystruct {
        int a;
        char* b;
        char* c;
    } e = {5, "blaat", "boe"}, f;

    return 0;
}
```